# HTML,CSS, image position

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to solve this problem. I have menu with height: 72px and logo with height: 117px. The logo is still with height: 72px. I do responsive design. I can make it with margin positioning, but I think this is not good for responsive.

[Picture](http://postimg.org/image/4msltdupt/)

Any ideas how to solve it? Thanks a lot

```
  @font-face{font-family: Exo-Bold; src:url(../fonts/Exo-Bold.otf);}
  @font-face{font-family: Exo-Light; src:url(../fonts/Exo-Light.otf);}
  body 
{
background-color: white;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
a 
{
text-decoration: none;
}
a:link, a:visited
{
color: white;
}
a:hover, a:active
{
color: white;
text-decoration: underline;
}
.header
{
background-image: url(../images/bg-img.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
height: 72px;
width: 100%;
}

.header .nav
{
height: 72px;
margin-left: 15%;
}
.header .nav ul
{
margin: 0 auto;
list-style-type: none;
}
.header .nav ul li
{
float:left;
display: inline-block;
font-family: Exo-Bold;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 25px 20px;
}
.logo
{
background-image:url(../images/logo.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 117px;
width: auto;
margin-left: 10%;
 }
```

Comment: So what you want to achieve is to have the logo always have the height of the `.header`?

Comment: I don' see a logo from your link. Can you post the relevant HTML here?

Comment: i want to menu with height: 72px and in this menu I want logo with height: 117px. So it should look like the picture here:

http://postimg.org/image/82bxvo3xl/

Comment: ok i solve this problem

Comment: Can you share the html structure as well? Try jsfiddle.